# Python crashes during training due to full RAM

Tags: python, ubuntu, jupyter-notebook, pytorch, archlinux

I'm trying to train a neural network on CT scans in pytorch on Arch Linux. After a few 3D-convolutions, my RAM fills up very quickly, then python crashes without an error message. This happens both when running it as a script or in a Jupyter notebook. I tried adding a swap partition to give myself a bit more time until my RAM is exhausted, but the swap fills up fairly quickly as well and once it is full, my program crashes again.

This also happens on my ubuntu installation, so I doubt it has anything to do with my system configuration. Is the only way to fix this to reduce the amount of memory I am using at once? If so, how would I go about doing this?

Answer (score -1):

Thats why you need to use a `DataLoader` object. Find it in `torch.utils.data.DataLoader`.